# How to access the blueprint of a widget from the game view

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unrealscript

I have joined a big game project but as I work in remote it's difficult find the right person to ask where I have to go in order to modify the comportment of the button currently on my game view.

So I would like to know if there is any way to: select the blueprint of one object displayed on the game view while running the game ?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, there is just no way of knowing what UMG/Slate widget class is currently displayed in the viewport, let alone going to the source by clicking on it...sorry.